# Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0

Tags: android, apk

APK build is working fine  but generating signed bundlle is failing with below error

"Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0."

I have creating code with Java not sure why Kotlin comes in picture..

Comment: any success with that? I've imported some lib and got this error when building release APK, before that try I've developed whole solution on debug without a problem...

Answer (score 0):

In your project level open build.gradle file, increase the ext.kotlin_version from whatever current version that you have like 1.5.0, to the latest stable version 1.6.0