# Incompatible version of Kotlin (metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0) after adding dependency

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-gradle-plugin

My project contains three modules: main - pure Java, 3rd-party app - pure Java and another 3rd-party app - Kotlin, `1.5.10`

Project isn't maintained, but still works and I've got a task to implement some lib in it, in main module. I've developed whole solution without a problem on debug, but now when I'm trying to build release APK I'm getting 4 errors in `:lintVitalBasicRelease` stage similar to below

```
..f4b73468ce598bb17f04/kotlin-stdlib-1.6.0.jar!/META-INF/kotlin-stdlib.kotlin_module:
Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin.
The binary version of its metadata is 1.6.0, expected version is 1.4.0.
```

same for `kotlin-stdlib-common-1.6.0.jar`, `preference-1.2.0.jar` and `slidingpanelayout-1.2.0.jar`, same versions 1.6/1.4 mentioned in all

project gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.10'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        ...
```

gradle for 3rd-party Kotlin app/module:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"


    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        
        ...
        
dependencies {
    compile "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    ...
```

main module (no Kotlin!):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        
        ...
        
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation('com.dji:dji-sdk:4.16.4', {
        exclude module: 'fly-safe-database'
    })
    compileOnly 'com.dji:dji-sdk-provided:4.16.4'
    ...
    implementation project(path: ':somekotlininhere')
    implementation project(path: ':purejavamodule')
}
```

without posted above implementation of [THIS SDK](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-Android) project is building and signing fine, I'm producing APK without a problem

fun fact that in linked sdk repo we can find [Sample Code](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-Android/tree/master/Sample%20Code), which have exactly same Kotlin version (1.5.10) and dependecies, even declared same way (using shared `ext.kotlin_version`)

updating Kotlin to newest one 1.8.10 introduced some new errors/deprecations, after resolving I've got back to same point and initial error... I've reverted this change back, I'm not an author of Kotlin-module, I would prefer to not touch

so: what is proper declarations for my case, how can I release my project now, as it works pretty good "via cable" (debug)

PS. yep, this question is a duplicate of [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73235104/module-was-compiled-with-an-incompatible-version-of-kotlin-the-binary-version-o), but I believe I've posted more useful and detailed info for resolving this...

Comment: If your dependency requires a more recent version of Kotlin and your project doesn't support it, then you need to use an older version of the dependency. Read the Release notes of the library to see what version would work better. Of course doing that way, you'll not have access to latest features and bug fix from the library but if you don't need them it's a way to proceed if you don't have time/can't migrate your project now

Comment: my 3rd-party module is written with `1.5.10`, is it safe to downgrade? I bet no, I've tried anyway with 1.4.32 and 1.6, same issue still. There is `1.6.0` `androix.core` `KTX` library, I've tried to manipulate also this version, this is adding even more similar issues (with different metadata number in errors)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe putting the following lines of code in the project's Gradle works for you

```
afterEvaluate {

    tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>().configureEach {
        kotlinOptions {
            apiVersion = "1.5"
            languageVersion = "1.5"
        }
    }
}
```

Or maybe you need just turn off your lint warning

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        //If you want to continue even if errors found use following line
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

But I didn't recommend those.

The most difficult way is upgrading your dependencies, but it's more reliable.

```
// use this dependency if your java target is 1.8 or above
org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:
```

In you're app Gradle use the following code depending on your Java version

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()
    }
}
```

Edited answer __________________________________

Also try following packaging option in your `app Gradle`:

```
android {
    ...
    
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        
        ndk {
            // On x86 devices that run Android API 23 or above, if the application is targeted with API 23 or
        // above, FFmpeg lib might lead to runtime crashes or warnings.
            abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        doNotStrip "*/*/libdjivideo.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libSDKRelativeJNI.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libFlyForbid.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libduml_vision_bokeh.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libyuv2.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libGroudStation.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libFRCorkscrew.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libUpgradeVerify.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libFR.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libDJIFlySafeCore.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libdjifs_jni.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libsfjni.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libDJICommonJNI.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libDJICSDKCommon.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libDJIUpgradeCore.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libDJIUpgradeJNI.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libDJIWaypointV2Core.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libAMapSDK_MAP_v6_9_2.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libDJIMOP.so"
        doNotStrip "*/*/libDJISDKLOGJNI.so"
        exclude 'META-INF/rxjava.properties'
        exclude 'assets/location_map_gps_locked.png'
        exclude 'assets/location_map_gps_3d.png'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

And this progaurd rule in your `app progaurd file`:

```
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,*Annotation*,Signature,EnclosingMethod

-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn org.bouncycastle.**
-dontwarn dji.**
-dontwarn com.dji.**
-dontwarn sun.**
-dontwarn java.**
-dontwarn com.amap.api.**
-dontwarn com.here.**
-dontwarn com.mapbox.**
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.**

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static <methods>;
}

-keepnames class * implements java.io.Serializable
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    !static !transient <fields>;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}
-keep class * extends android.os.Parcelable {
    public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

-keep,allowshrinking class * extends dji.publics.DJIUI.** {
    public <methods>;
}

-keep class net.sqlcipher.** { *; }

-keep class net.sqlcipher.database.* { *; }

-keep class dji.** { *; }

-keep class com.dji.** { *; }

-keep class com.google.** { *; }

-keep class org.bouncycastle.** { *; }

-keep,allowshrinking class org.** { *; }

-keep class com.squareup.wire.** { *; }

-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }

-keep class com.secneo.** { *; }

-keep class org.greenrobot.eventbus.**{*;}

-keep class it.sauronsoftware.ftp4j.**{*;}

-keepclasseswithmembers,allowshrinking class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer

-keep class androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView { *; }

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Service
-keepclassmembers public class * extends android.view.View {
    void set*(***);
    *** get*();
}
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
    public void *(android.view.View);
}
-keep class androidx.** { *; }
-keep class android.media.** { *; }
-keep class okio.** { *; }
-keep class com.lmax.disruptor.** { *; }
-keep class com.qx.wz.dj.rtcm.* { *; }

-dontwarn com.mapbox.services.android.location.LostLocationEngine
-dontwarn com.mapbox.services.android.location.MockLocationEngine
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver {
    <init>(...);
}
# ViewModel's empty constructor is considered to be unused by proguard
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModel {
    <init>(...);
}
# keep Lifecycle State and Event enums values
-keepclassmembers class android.arch.lifecycle.Lifecycle$State { *; }
-keepclassmembers class android.arch.lifecycle.Lifecycle$Event { *; }
# keep methods annotated with @OnLifecycleEvent even if they seem to be unused
# (Mostly for LiveData.LifecycleBoundObserver.onStateChange(), but who knows)
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.arch.lifecycle.OnLifecycleEvent *;
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver {
    <init>(...);
}

-keep class * implements android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleObserver {
    <init>(...);
}
-keepclassmembers class android.arch.** { *; }
-keep class android.arch.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.arch.**

-keep class org.apache.commons.** {*;}


#<------------ utmiss config start------------>
-keep class dji.sdk.utmiss.** { *; }
-keep class utmisslib.** { *; }
#<------------ utmiss config end------------>
```

Hope this pushing you forward :)

Comment: thanks for answer, but it didn't pushed me forward... first way with `afterEvaluate` - pasted into project gradle at the end shows _<expression> expected, got )_ suggesting that inside `()` there should be some argument. disabling lint - produces apk, which is crashing on start on mentioned lib native internal dependency (debug build works fine).

Comment: stdlib way - tried to exchange `kotlin-stdlib-jdk7` to `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8` and "pure" `kotlin-stdlib` (all in `$kotlin_version` version), but still same issue. also putting `kotlinOptions` in Kotlin-module gradle doesn't change anything, source and target already declared `JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8` in main-not-Kotlin-module

Comment: I edited my answer plz check it out

Comment: I already have `abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'` (this is old project, only 32 bit), `packagingOptions` and `compileOptions` set for Java 8. also I've already added related lines to proguard, but even disabling proguard at all doesn't help, same `1.6/1.4` error

Comment: For the last thing, can you give same value to your compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion in your main Module Gradle and your third party Gradle.

Comment: `compileSdkVersion 31`, `targetSdkVersion 27`, `minSdkVersion 21`. I can't ++ for target, API 28 breaks one of the features... `buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'`